# in RapidMiner how do I run the same read database query while looping through supplied values

Tags: foreach, rapidminer

Given a database table how do I use macros to change the "where" value of a select query to incorporate the distinct values from a column in that table using rapidminer?

For example if the column was "city" and the distinct values were {London, NewYork,Paris} how do I use macros and loops so a subprocess will run the following statement?

```
Select * from Table where city = SuppliedValue
```

My problem is really down to reading the distinct values into a variable and looping for each value found but I can't get my head around if I should use optimize parameter grid, loop operator (and which 1) or a macro operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the `Loop Values` operator to select each of the possible values of an attribute. The inner operators within the loop are called once for each value of the attribute and a macro is set to this value that can be used by these operators. Inside the loop, a SQL query can be executed using `Read Database` and this query can use the macro.

For example if the supplied values are "London" and "Paris" contained in an attribute called "City" then `Loop Values` would be configured with this attribute. The default macro name is `loop_value`. Inside the loop, use a `Read Database` operator and setup its SQL statement to be  something like this

`select * from Table where city like '%{loop_value}'`

The example set output from the SQL read can be connected to the output of the loop operator which in turn will output 2 examples sets and these will have to be handled as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. To try it I created a new process with a generate data operator (target function transaction, 100 rows, 5 attribs) and connected it to a loop values operator but when I do, the loop operator doesn't display any of the 5 attribs to loop which do show in the metadata for the generated eg set if i output it to an result port directly. Would you have any idea why? If I add generate attribs operator between generate data and loop and create a new attrib with a rand() function that attrib is listed in loop operator so from eg set with 6 numeric attribs  only 1 can be looped?

Comment: `Loop Values` loops through all the possible values of one attribute which has to be chosen as the attribute parameter. It only works for nominal attributes since numerical values could have as many different values as there are examples in the example set. Change the `Generate Data` operator to use the `two gaussians classification` and select the attribute `label` in the `Loop Values` operator. Ensure that inside `Loop Values`, the input is directly connected to the output. You should see two example sets being created corresponding to the two possible values for the label.

Comment: Are there ways to go from numeric to nominal ?

Comment: The `Discretize by` operators are the ones to use.